# Best way to voltage divider a output from a precision oscillator

Tags: oscillator

I have a design where I'm using a oxco oscillator with a CMOS 0-4.3V output and the input Xin IC requires a Max of 2.4VPP.

What is the best way to descrease the voltage?
I've experimented a simple resistor or capacitor voltage divider and the chip works but is this the recommended solution? Or there's a better way designed for high precision oscillators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you say right in your title: A simple voltage divider will do that. So, two resistors.  There's really plenty of material explaining how you can calculate the ratio between these two resistors, so I'm leaving you with that.

You will have to take into account the drive strength of your oscillator's output, so that you don't overload it.

You will also have to take into account the impedance of your input, so that you don't load the voltage divider too much.

You didn't tell us the frequency of your oscillator, but if it's high frequency (say, > 10 MHz on a large board), then you'll also want matching your whole system to a single transmission impedance – but I don't see that happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a linear regulator. Resistive divider networks are not known to provided a stable output voltage.

Comment: A linear regulator is what you use for providing a stable supply voltage. This is the opposite use case: you need to keep the sharpness and low-jitter of a non-constant voltage what it is. **Not** a use case for a linear regulator!

Comment: @MarcusMüller My mistake then. Thanks for pointing that out!